# C++ - is it possible to generate every single permutation of an array, once and only once, using random_shuffle?

Tags: c++, arrays, random, permutation, shuffle

I have been tasked with testing a sorting algorithm by 'feeding' it every single permutation of an array of lenght 'n' once. I am supposed to do it with random_shuffle.

I know that random_shuffle follows an uniform distribution - that is, each permutation has equal chances of being generated - but that does not mean every permutation will be generated once before getting a repeated result, right? Say, if the first result is 12345, it should take 5! used of random_shuffle to get a repeated 12345 result. But that's not what's happening. I'm getting repeated results way too often. This is the code I'm using:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int v[5]={1,2,3,4,5}, w[5], cuenta=1;
memcpy(w,v,sizeof v);
srand(time(0));

do {
    random_shuffle(v,v+5);
    for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
        cout << v[j];
    cout << endl;
    cuenta++;
    cout << cuenta << endl;
    } while (memcmp(w,v,sizeof v));
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is that just the way random_shuffle operates?

**edit:**

I am aware that next::permutation would make way more sense. I am aware that this is overcomplicating things. But my teacher insists that I do it this way, that I shouldn't be getting repeated results since random_shuffle follows an uniform distribution; thus contradicting everything I've read including the documentation. I *have* to use random_shuffle. I am merely looking for confirmation / specific behaviour of this function. And even then, next_permutation is not random.

Comment: random has no such guarantee. If you flip a coin x times, there is a (slight) chance that it will always land on the same face. Getting all permutations is NOT random

Comment: Make a list of all permutations of the list. (Read: A list of lists.) Randomly shuffle the list of lists. Sufficient for your needs?

Comment: using `next_permutation` is a much easier way !

Comment: `next_permutation` is not random. It is based off of lexicographic order. Randomization appears to be a requirement.

Comment: Not sure if you missed my suggestion or if it was not sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Your teacher is incorrect. Sorry.

Comment: @Zéychin Sorry for the late reply. I have considered that, but it would take a lot of memory to store all the permutations, wouldn't it? Still, it seems like it's the only way (if there's such a thing as "the only way" in programming). Thanks for the help

Comment: Your teacher is a moron. For any reasonably large array, the amount of time needed to reach every permutation randomly might be years, and might even be never if the generator isn't seeded with sufficient entropy.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice n=5. That's small enough that your teacher might not be an idiot, just giving you a weird assignment.

Comment: Oh, it would mostly certainly take an extraordinary amount of memory for any considerably large n. That being said, it does satisfy all of your requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have to use `random_shuffle`? That seems like the wrong algorithm for this function, since there's no guarantee on how many attempts you need to actually get all your `n!` different permutations. A more suited algorithm would be `std::next_permutation`. As in:

```
 do {
     // test your sort
 } while (std::next_permutation(v, v+5));
```

With `random_shuffle`, you'd have to actually check to see if this is a permutation you've done before and do all this extra work to make sure you didn't miss one. I mean, if you **have** to use it for an assignment, you have to use it, but I'd try not to :)

[UPDATE] I just had a thought. Maybe your teacher just wants you to try lots of different permutations, not necessarily all of them? Like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    std::random_shuffle(v, v+5);
    // test your sort
}
```

That *might* test all permutations. It might not. But I feel like it'd be pretty unlikely for your sort to be broken and this to pass.

Comment: I added an edit adressing that. I know it makes way more sense to use next_permutation, but I HAVE to use random_shuffle. Thank you very much for the input

Comment: @Kovalainen Lemme know if the update sounds reasonable at all. It's really the only reasonable way I can think of to use `random_shuffle`.

Answer (score 2):

It's very unlikely that every permutation will be generated once before getting a repeated result; thus `random_shuffle()` is not what you want. Each call to `random_shuffle()` is independent of the other calls.

`next_permutation()` is probably what you want instead. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/

Comment: next_permutation is not random. It is based off of lexicographic order. Randomization appears to be a requirement.